# Reading memory with offsets using JNI

Tags: java, c++, memory, java-native-interface, offset

I'm trying to make a a custom system that can be easily adapted to a variety of games with the purpose of healing your character when your HP reaches a certain mark. this will be useful in the way that it will allow users to heal themselves with either potions or heal spells whenever they are in danger of dying. So far I've tested it in skyrim and I've gotten it to work fairly well but I want to make this game work on java code not Visual Basic. So basically I just need some help converting a small section of my VB code that reads memory into Java code. Also I expect that I'll have to use JNI but haven't done all that much JNI so please don't just direct me straight to the api.

```
    DWORD HpPointer = 0x007C5710; //example pointer
DWORD HpPointed;
WORD HpOffset = 0x07B4; //example offset
int CurrentHp = 0;      //variable that stores the integer value returned

ReadProcessMemory(hProc,(LPCVOID)(HpPointer), &HpPointed, 4, NULL);
ReadProcessMemory(hProc,(LPCVOID)(HpPointed+HpOffset), &CurrentHp, 4, NULL);
//end of hp section
return (CurrentHp);
```

Thanks

Comment: These are all OS-specific functions. So yes, you'll need to learn how to use JNI. I suggest Googling for a JNI tutorial, as it's too broad a subject to cover in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something line the following:

```
public class Game {

    public native byte[] readMemory(int offset);

}
```

You'd use

```
javah Game
```

to create the headers

Then you'd create your C++ class and include the headers in your program

To load the Game class, you'll either need to use System.loadLibrary() or use the -D command line parameters. Note: System.loadLibrary depends on the OS your running under. So if you compiling under Windows it will be a .dll file. For linux is will be a .so and for mac it will be a .jnilib extension

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I'm now very confused. Why does the JNI readMemory function only ask for an offset of int type while my c++ function takes so much more? Would you mind giving me the exact code in java that relates to ReadProcessMemory(). In the meantime I'm going to write a VB script that writes to a file and read the values from there.

Comment: You can't read direct memory using Java that's why you have to use JNI. The C/C++ program will handle reading the memory and return the result to java in the form of a byte array.